# Slide UIView part way over to expose another view and make exposed view interactable?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, menu

I want to create a basic version of the slide out menus that apps like Barclays Bank and Facebook use, I don't want to use a pod that has already been created as it adds complexity to the project when new versions etc comes out (have to wait for the developer to update compatibility etc).

So I have the idea to present the menu view under the current on screen view and then slide the current view part way over which will expose the uiview that is under this.

This works fine however I have an issue and just trying to work out the best way around it....

When the top view slides over to expose the underneath view (menu) I also want to pass control to that exposed view so I can interact with it and not the top view?

Any ideas on best way to achieve this?

Comment: why would you like to interact with the menu, and not the top view? Do you wanna feed some data to the menu?

Comment: Whilst the menu is exposed I only want to interact with that view which is actually underneath the moved over top view

Comment: hmm, that sounds super strange for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually sorted it, had to create a view controller that had a uiview and a container view, with the container view over the uiview. This allowed me to move the view over and still interface with the uiview as I want swapping view controllers on the nav stack.

Answer (score 0):

```
 topViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = false
```

Comment: Setting user interaction disabled doesn't work as that stops interaction with the top view but doesn't enable interaction with the view below